# Can a sentential relative clause also be a non-restrictive one?

Tags: relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

I have to answer the following question:

> He kicked at my door, which was totally unacceptable
>  a) There are two adverbials
>  b) The relative clause is **sentential**
>  c) The relative
> clause is non-restrictive 
> d) Door is the antecedent

The answer sheet suggests that a) and b) are the correct answers but I wonder why c) isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

> *He kicked at my door, which was totally unacceptable.*

We don’t talk of 'sentential relative clauses', since that suggests the relative clause is a sentence, which it isn’t.

What we have here is a relative clause with a clause as antecedent – a possibility that is found only with the supplementary (non-restrictive) type.

The preposition phrase "at my door" is an adjunct, and "totally" is an adverb modifying "unacceptable".

Comment: Thank you but this assignment was created by my lecturer, so he talks about sentential RCs. 
Unfortunately, I have to deal with the possible answers given!

Comment: @alinavethacke So you have my full support in telling your lecturer that he is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If the relative clause is "sentential" then it refers to the whole action.  This relative clause doesn't describe or identify the door, so it shouldn't be considered a non-restrictive, nor a restrictive modification of the noun door.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you! 
Is it possible to state that a relative clause is either sentential or restrictive, or non-restrictive?

Comment: Yes, but these are not grammatical categories.  They are descriptions of the meaning of the clause, and meanings are always fuzzy and context dependent.

Comment: Thank you so much!